# How many additional verses are there in Vijayadwaja's edition of Bhagavata Purana?

Tags: bhagavata-purana

From Dvaita tradition, Vijayadhwaja has commentary on the whole Bhagavata Purana. There are many additional verses/chapters in the edition that he used compared to Sridhara Svami's recension(which ISKCON/BBT is close to).

How many additional verses are there in Vijayadhwaja's text?